# Why there is AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.contrib.eager' has no attribute 'Variable' in TensorFlow 1.15?

Tags: python, tensorflow, eager-execution

I had run a neural style transfer notebook tutorial in Google Colab successfully around one month ago. However, this week I can't run the exact same notebook successfully, with the following error message: 
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.contrib.eager' has no attribute 'Variable'.

I checked that the Notebook in Google Colab is using TensorFlow 1.15, and when I checked the API documentation, the Variable method exist: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/eager/Variable

What is the reason for this error message?

Comment: Please post a minimal code example with a full error traceback.

Answer (score 0):

In Tensorflow 1.15 `tensorflow.contrib.eager.Variable` doesn't exist. Although shown in the documentation, it is marked as deprecated and doesn't seem to be in the code at all.

Use the regular old `tf.Variable` instead. The following code works fine in 1.15:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution()

x = tf.Variable(1, dtype=tf.float32)
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    f = x * x
print(tape.gradient(f, x))
```

`>> tf.Tensor(2.0, shape=(), dtype=float32)`